# I want to send to multiple recipients in "To" field but no one can see other email recipients

Tags: gmail

Actually I want to promote my website based on that I want to send multiple emails addresses in the "To" field. I don't want to use "Bcc" field because it's only one to one relation. Without using "Bcc" how can I send multiple recipients in "To" field in Gmail?

Comment: You say that `bcc` is only one to one relation. Do you mean that you want the others to relate to eachother somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the same message to multiple people, but you don't want them to see all of the people to whom the message was sent, the traditional way is to use the `bcc` field.

If you don't want to use `bcc`, but you don't want to leak everyone's email address by having multiple people in the `to` field, you need to send individual messages to each person.

It sounds like what you need is a bulk mailing service.